# How to know if a word is at the end of a line in C

Tags: c, string

So I need to solve a problem where I have to read words from a file and still be able to recognize if a word is at the end of a line. For example:

```
This is a test file
I need to distinguish every word
and still be able to print out every words that are at the end of a line
```

I tried using:

```
while(scanf("%s", string) != EOF){
len = strlen(string);
if (string[len] == '\n'){
printf("%s is a word at the end of a line", string);
}
}
```

but nothing seems to be properly working.
Can somebody help me?

Edit 1: I have tried

```
if (string[len-1] == '\n')
```

but it gives the last character of the word instead. For example the word string[len-1] of "file" is 'e' even though it's the word that's at the end of line 1

Comment: After executing  `len = strlen(string)`, then `string[len]` will be the `nul` character! You need to check `string[len-1]`.

Comment: I have tried `string[len-1]` but it gives the last character of each words instead. Like `string[len-1]` for "file" gives 'e' and not '\n'

Comment: Read with `fgets()` into a sufficiently sized buffer, and then use either `strtok` or `sscanf` utilizing the `"%n"` specifier to obtain the number of characters consumed on each call so you can update your buffer index to be ready for the call to parse the next word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scanf` call reads words, returning one each time. It skips over both spaces and newlines, so there is no way you can look at one of the words to see if it was at the end of a line. You need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using scanf("%[^\n]") instead of %s so you can read until end of line, after that, you read your string from end to first space to get the last word